# Socket connection between Python and TCL

Tags: python, tcl, python-sockets

I've just started on socket programming. I want to have the client as TCL and server as Python. I tried the following few scripts, but I'm unable to make any progress.

Here are my scripts:

**server.py**:

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 45000))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    clt, adr=s.accept()
    print(adr)
    clt.send(bytes("Socket programming in Python"))
```

**client.tcl**:

```
set host "127.0.0.1"
set port 45000 
set mysock [socket -myaddr $host -myport $port $host $port]
fconfigure $mysock -buffering none
gets $mysock line
close $mysock
puts "Message is $line"
```

However, the above TCL script just hangs and doesn't go beyond the gets command.

This is the equivalent Python client script which works:

**client.py**:

```
import socket 
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
print(s) 
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 45000)) 
msg=s.recv(1024) 
print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

Now based on few suggestions, to mimic the above python client script in TCL, I tried the following:

**client_modified.tcl**:

```
set s [socket [info hostname] 45000]
puts $s
fconfigure $s -translation binary
puts [encoding convertfrom utf-8 [read $s 28]]
```

I'm still not able to proceed beyond: "socket localhost 45000".

It gives me the error:

```
> tclsh client.tcl 
couldn't open socket: connection refused
    while executing
"socket [info hostname] 45000"
    invoked from within
"set s [socket [info hostname] 45000]"
```

Can anyone please guide here.

Comment: You might find this answer helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/24057311/475482. It might point you to a reason why your server and client can't communicate.  Then take a look at what IP you are binding to in your python server and see if it is the same as the tcl client IP you are using.

Comment: In socket programming, specifying `-myaddr` and `-myport` (or their equivalent in other languages) is _really_ rare. It's very unusual to set the local address of a client socket, and it _adds failure modes_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that:

```
import socket 
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
print(s) 
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 45000)) 
msg=s.recv(1024) 
print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

is a *working* Python client, the equivalent in Tcl is:

```
set s [socket [info hostname] 45000]
puts $s
fconfigure $s -translation binary
puts [encoding convertfrom utf-8 [read $s 28]]; # You're writing 28 bytes, not 1024
```

But I'd be more inclined to write:

```
set s [socket localhost 45000]; # For complex reasons, [info hostname] takes a long time on macOS
fconfigure $s -encoding utf-8
puts [read $s 28]
```

Note that if you're writing text data over a socket, you *really* should also write newlines to act as a message boundary. On the Tcl side, this would let you use `gets` instead of `read`; without the newline, Tcl's `gets` will merrily wait indefinitely for it to turn up when in the default blocking mode. (For binary-oriented protocols, you'd probably be sending the length of data first if that's variable.)

A more sophisticated version uses non-blocking mode. Unless you're *really* sure what you're doing, non-blocking mode should be used exclusively with `fileevent` callbacks:

```
set s [socket localhost 45000]
fconfigure $s -encoding utf-8 -blocking 0
fileevent $s readable {apply {{} {
    global s done
    puts [read $s 1024]
    # Remember to close that socket at EOF
    if {[eof $s]} {
        close $s
        set done "ok"; # Terminates the event loop running this
    }
}}}
vwait done; # Launch an event loop for processing the socket
```

If you write messages back to the server, you probably want to set `-buffering none` so that you don't have to fuss around with `flush`. And if you're doing a complex conversation, you'll probably want to use a coroutine to manage it; they've got features for complex programming (and some support libraries exist to help) that make doing complex protocols enormously simpler.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying it in Unix and I'm still not able to proceed beyond: "socket localhost 45000". It gives me the error  "couldn't open socket: connection refused
    while executing
"socket [info hostname] 45000"
    invoked from within
"set s [socket [info hostname] 45000]"
"

Comment: Part of the problem is that you're binding the server to a specific interface. You don't normally do that; it's usual to leave the hostname part as INADDR_ANY ([the empty string](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/socket.html) in Python).

Answer (score 0):

On the Tcl side, to open a client socket, do not specify `-myport`.  This option specifies a particular port for the client connection to use.  Since your code sets this to port 45000, which is already in use by the server, it fails.

```
set host "127.0.0.1"
set port 45000
try {
  set mysock [socket $host $port]
} on error { err res } {
  puts $res
}
try {
  chan configure $mysock -buffering line
  chan configure $mysock -encoding utf-8
} on error { err res } {
  puts $res
}
try {
  gets $mysock line
} on error { err res } {
  puts $res
}
puts "Message is $line"
close $mysock
```

I changed the python code to include a newline so that it would flush the message.  Not knowing any python or how the python socket code works, I got lucky there.

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 45000))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    clt, adr=s.accept()
    print(adr)
    clt.send(bytes("Socket programming in Python\n"))
```

Comment: The python binding to `socket.gethostname()` probably isn't ideal either, but I don't know python well enough to know what its version of `INADDR_ANY` is. (Or how to make it use just localhost)

Comment: My connection is not getting established without -myport option:
Error: couldn't open socket: connection refused

Comment: In general, a connection refused error indicates that there is no server listening.

Answer (score 0):

It works with the following small edit(-async):

```
set s [socket -async [info hostname] 45000]
puts $s
fconfigure $s -translation binary
puts [encoding convertfrom utf-8 [read $s 28]]
```

Thanks for helping.